# Prometheus alertmanager persistent storage with docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prometheus-alertmanager

For some reason I can't get persistent storage to work with alertmanager.
This is my compose:

```
  alertmanager:
    image: 'my/alertmanager/prod:latest'
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - alertmanager-data:/alertmanager-data
    command:
      - '--config.file=/alertmanager/alertmanager-config.yml'
      - '--storage.path=/alertmanager-data'
    ports:
      - 9103:9093

  volumes:
    alertmanager-data:
      external: true
```

I have created the volume and everything seems to initialise correctly.
But after entering the machine */alertmanager-data* doesn't seem to contain any DB or files. And creating new silences on the alertmanager never persist.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: @Mark Yes. It turns out that it actually does work, but it takes a while for it to write memory to storage. I don't remember how often it is stored but it takes some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Moved from comment for visibility
```

> It turns out that it actually does work, but it takes a while for it
> to write memory to storage. I don't remember how often it is stored
> but it takes some time.

Comment: Any insight on what the time persistence time is? Is it configurable? In the alertmanager flags i found `--alerts.gc-interval=30m` , maybe changing this value persists alerts faster

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this change https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/pull/2849/files It looks like it used to be persisted to disk every 15 minutes, and now that is configurable with the parameter `--data.maintenance-interval` since version 0.25